# after finish function start new function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

my question is:

How can I Start a function in Google Apps Scripts, if a function finished? Example:

```
Function A() {


Return EndA
}


Function B{

If (EndA = False) { Function A() }

}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By calling it? Learn the basics of Javascript.

Comment: I Know how to call a function. The Thing is, I want to start the function after the first function FINISHED.

Comment: So call it at the end of the function? (or after you call the function)

Comment: Are you actually asking how to write asynchronous code?

Comment: he's asking how to write function callbacks. functions that execute when a deed is done, so yeah, asynchronous, hahaha

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. My problem was, that at the end of the function, there was en error message. So if I called the second Function in the first function, it wasnt executed, because the first function stopped inside. So i have got a new method to solve this problem:     function AllFunctions() {

try {
    Function A();
}
catch(err) {
    FunctionA();
} 
finally {
   FunctionB();
}


}

Answer (score 0):

You could call function B at the end of function A.

```
function A() {
    ....
    B();
}

function B() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. My problem was, that at the end of the function, there was en error message. So if I called the second Function in the first function, it wasnt executed, because the first function stopped inside. So i have got a new method to solve this problem:     function AllFunctions() {

try {
    Function A();
}
catch(err) {
    FunctionA();
} 
finally {
   FunctionB();
}

Answer (score 0):

Check this [async function guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in JS from Mozilla.
There's also a video guide by Net Ninja about [Async Javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxWMxJONp7E&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jAhrjtZ9U93UMIhnCc44MH).